# Annoying error message: cannot merge previous GCDA file

Tags: c++, qt, code-coverage

**Problem**:

I'm using the following flags to generate the code coverage of my **Qt** application (`.pro` file):

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --coverage
QMAKE_LFLAGS += --coverage
```

The code coverage is correctly generated, the problem is that if I want to run only one test function/class (and the **GCDA** files were already created) I get the following error message:

```
profiling: /Users/user/.../build-myapp/myclass.gcda: cannot merge previous GCDA file: corrupt arc tag (0x00000000)
```

Note that the error message is shown for each **GCDA** file. Also, note that it doesn't seem to affect the test cases.

---

**Workaround**:

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519530/dozens-of-profilinginvalid-arc-tag-when-running-code-coverage-in-xcode-5), it "*is a result of the build tools failing to merge current results into the existing .gcda coverage files*". As answered in the question, an option is to delete the GCDA files before running the tests. For example, by adding the following command in the build phase:

```
find . -name "*.gcda" -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

---

**Question**:

My problem is that I don't want to delete the old GCDA files every time I run the test cases. As I'm running only one test function/class, I want to keep the old GCDA files as they are, and only merge the GCDA file related to the current class. As I manually checked, it is already being done because only the coverage of my current class is updated, and the old coverages remain the same.

**So, is there a command to just ignore (don't show) the error messages related to the GCDA merging problems? Or even better, a command to only update the GCDA files related to the current test class?**

**Note**: I'm using Qt 5.3.2 on macOS Sierra with Clang.

---

**Related questions**:

- [Code coverage warnings spam output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936659/code-coverage-warrnings-spam-output)
- [How to merge multiple versions of gcda files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25059435/how-to-merge-multiple-versions-of-gcda-files)
- [.gcda files don't merge on multiple runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492859/gcda-files-dont-merge-on-multiple-runs)

Answer (score 5):

When you compile with profiling, the results of each run are stored in a file that ends with `.gcda`.

The error appears when your existing `.gcda` file is in a different format than the current program that just finished running.

This happened to me when I had run a Linux version of my executable, then recompiled for MacOS and ran it. The MacOS program saw the existing `.gcda` file and generated pages of errors.

Eliminate the errors by removing the existing `.gcda` file.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem. My solution is:

1. There is a general `Test.pro` project which uses `SUBDIRS` to include every test project as subproject.
2. In each test subproject I have the following line

   `QMAKE_POST_LINK = rm -f "*.gcda"`

This deletes the *.gcda files only for the subproject which was just relinked. Unmodified projects keep their *.gcda files.